# How to have a table spanning a 2-column paper (i.e. IEEE Transactions), with appropriate widths for each column heading?

Tags: tables

Here is a MWE, but it results in a table with a large empty area on the right. How can I change that so that it is neatly spanning the width of the page?

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Values of The Tan Logistic Map.}
\label{tab:TanTable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{5}{C}c@{}}
\toprule
  $(x,y)$                   & $(x,y)\times 10^7$                  & Whole Number $(x,y)$\\

\midrule  
\addlinespace
($0.3$, $0.3$)               & ($3000000$, $3000000$)               & ($3000000$, $3000000$) \\
\addlinespace
($1.04652$, $3.02357$)       & ($10465258.317$, $30235701.7895$)    & ($10465258$, $30235701$)\\
\addlinespace
($-0.63019$, $-2.3607$)      & ($7346647.71148$, $6264212.567803$)  & ($7346647$, $6264212$) \\
\addlinespace
($0.73466$, $0.626421$)      & ($13410269.9471$, $26680129.5641$)   & ($13410269$, $26680129$) \\
\addlinespace
($1.34102$, $-53.8349$)      & ($5695430.16272$, $102796485.5180$)  & ($5695430$, $102796485$) \\
\addlinespace
($-1.97806$, $2.668012$)     & ($52553839.66069$, $14999801.7764$)  & ($52553839$, $14999801$) \\
\addlinespace

% \midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please pots a *complete* document, not just a snippet. What is the `C`column type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```latex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \newcolumntype{b}{X}
    \newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Values of The Tan Logistic Map.}
    \label{tab:TanTable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lll@{}}
      $(x,y)$                   & $(x,y)\times 10^7$                  & Whole Number $(x,y)$\\



    ($0.3$, $0.3$)               & ($3000000$, $3000000$)               & ($3000000$, $3000000$) \\

    ($1.04652$, $3.02357$)       & ($10465258.317$, $30235701.7895$)    & ($10465258$, $30235701$)\\

    ($-0.63019$, $-2.3607$)      & ($7346647.71148$, $6264212.567803$)  & ($7346647$, $6264212$) \\

    ($0.73466$, $0.626421$)      & ($13410269.9471$, $26680129.5641$)   & ($13410269$, $26680129$) \\

    ($1.34102$, $-53.8349$)      & ($5695430.16272$, $102796485.5180$)  & ($5695430$, $102796485$) \\

    ($-1.97806$, $2.668012$)     & ($52553839.66069$, $14999801.7764$)  & ($52553839$, $14999801$) \\



    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Having tweaked your code a bit I could not find any blank space on the right side.
Is this what you were looking for?